# One dictionary changes value while I'm working on another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm struggling with dictionaries

```
dic1 = {"A":"a","B":"b","C":"c"}
dic2 = dic1
dic2["D"]="d"
print(dic1)
```

output:

```
{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd'}
```

Could someone explain me why dic1 also appended "D" key with "d" value? And what can I do to avoid this problem? I really want dic1 to not change values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're working with references. [This guide](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-references/) is a great explanation of Python references.

To avoid this problem, try the following:

```
dic1 = {"A":"a","B":"b","C":"c"}
dic2 = dic1.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fundamental property of Python objects. When you naively assign an existed object to a new one, the new one actually points to the first object.
With `dict2 = dict1`, you are actually pointing to the same object. That means every change you make in `dict2` will affect the original object.
In case you want to copy a dictionary, try `dict2  = dict(dict1)`.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Good to learn new thing